# YAML subsequent as substring

Tags: variables, yaml, interpreter

How to use variables in YAML? Let's get the code

```
hr:
  - Mark McGwire
  - &SS Sammy Sosa
rbi:
  - *SS
  - Lorem *SS ipsum
  - Ken Griffey
```

The

```
  - *SS
```

line returns `Sammy Sosa` string that is OK.

But the

```
  - Lorem *SS ipsum
```

line returns `Lorem *SS ipsum` string as it takes the subsequent `*SS` literally and does not interpret it.

Comment: You can't do this with YAML alone. You'll have to use a programming language to do more complex substitutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no variable substitution in YAML scalars. What you refer to in your example is the use of [anchor node](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2785586)s (starting with `&`) and [aliases nodes](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786196) (starting with a `*`), which help to be able to construct self-referencing structures in YAML.

The aliases always refer to complete nodes, and only in the case of [merge key](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html) can one or more **mapping**s be inserted as a part of the new structure. There is no such feature for insertion within scalars as you us in your last example, you can only substitute the complete (scalar) node.

Comment: Thanks. Good explanation.

Comment: If this solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer (clicking the V to the left of it), that way this post is marked as resolved without people needing to open the post and scroll to your comment.